# Why doesn't LinkedHashSet have addFirst method?

Tags: java, linked-list, deque, linkedhashset

As the documentation of `LinkedHashSet` states, it is

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries.

So it's essentially a `HashSet` with FIFO queue of keys implemented by a linked list. Considering that `LinkedList` is `Deque` and permits, in particular, insertion at the beginning, I wonder why doesn't `LinkedHashSet` have the `addFirst(E e)` method in addition to the methods present in the `Set` interface. It seems not hard to implement this.

Comment: adding to a linked hash set has the same meaning as addFirst would

Comment: @RoyShahaf Are you sure? `add` for `LinkedList` is equivalent to `addLast`. `addFirst` has different meaning.

Comment: When would an `addFirst` function be useful?

Comment: Because `LinkedHashSet` preserves insertion order. That's it. There isn't a way to manipulate that order. Also, if you add methods not in the interface, then you can't program to the common interface anymore.

Comment: @thatotherguy In the same cases when it is useful with `LinkedList`. For example, to create LIFO queue.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If traversal order matters, you're usually already using a more specific type.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `TreeSet` contains a bunch of methods not present in `Set`.

Comment: [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) says (in part) *This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order).* Did you want a [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)?

Comment: @JohnMcClane my bad :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This sentence concerns ordinary insertion, via `Set.add` method. They could have added to it that `addFirst` changes this order. By the way, this phrase is not completely correct. Try to add 1, then 2 to `LinkedHashSet<Integer>`, then remove 1, then add it again, and you'll see that the iteration order is now `2, 1` that contradicts the fact that 1 was inserted **earlier** than 2.

Comment: You removed an element in the middle. Should it have infinite memory to store all of the values that you have removed? Regardless, what problem are you trying solve?

Comment: I don't think anyone except the original authors can answer this. We cannot even tell for sure whether it was a deliberate decision, let alone any potential reasons.

Comment: @Marvin I think such decisions are always considered. Even if it was overlooked at the earlier versions of Java, nothing prevents from adding this method, as it was with `String.isBlank()` in Java 11. For me, it seems natural to include it. But maybe there was some reason not to do this?

Comment: a general rule is to keep interfaces as thin as possible

Comment: @RoyShahaf I agree with this, but here we're not expanding the `Set` interface, but only adding one class-specific method.

Comment: When you write a library, any API you make available must be supported (pretty much) forever.
This is even more so when writing a language and its base libraries.
The use-case for a LinkedHashSet is obvious, the use-case for addFirst in a LinkedHashSet is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eliott Frisch said, the answer is in the next sentence of the paragraph you quoted:

> … This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order
>   in which elements were inserted into the set (*insertion-order*). …

An `addFirst` method would break the insertion order and thereby the design idea of `LinkedHashSet`.

If I may add a bit of guesswork too, other possible reasons might include:

- It’s not so simple to implement as it appears since a `LinkedHashSet` is really implemented as a `LinkedHasMap` where the values mapped to are not used. At least you would have to change that class too (which in turn would also break *its* insertion order and thereby its design idea).
- As that other guy may have intended in a comment, they didn’t find it useful.

That said, you are asking the question the wrong way around. They designed a class with a functionality for which they saw a need. They moved on to implement it using a hash table and a linked list. You are starting out from the implementation and using it as a basis for a design discussion. While that may occasionally add something useful, generally it’s not the way to good designs.

While I can in theory follow your point that there might be a situation where you want a double-ended queue with set property (duplicates are ignored/eliminated), I have a hard time imagining when a `Deque` would not fulfil your needs in this case (Eliott Frisch mentioned the under-used `ArrayDeque`). You need pretty large amounts of data and/or pretty strict performance requirements before the linear complexity of `contains` and `remove` would be prohibitive. And in that case you may already be better off custom designing your own data structure.

Answer (score 3):

As of Java 21, `LinkedHashSet` does have an [`addFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html#addFirst(E)) method.

> `public void addFirst(E e)`
>
> Adds an element as the first element of this collection (optional operation). After this operation completes normally, the given element will be a member of this collection, and it will be the first element in encounter order.
>
> If this set already contains the element, it is relocated if necessary so that it is first in encounter order.
>
> **Specified by:**
> [`addFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html#addFirst(E)) in interface [`SequencedCollection<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html)`
>
> **Parameters:**
> `e` - the element to be added
>
> **Since:**
> 21

The `addFirst` method was added as part of the [JEP 431: Sequenced Collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431) feature added in Java 21.

The sequenced collections feature adds three new interfaces: [`SequencedCollection`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html), [`SequencedSet`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) (which extends `SequencedCollection`), and [`SequencedMap`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html).  Existing classes and interfaces have been retrofitted to used the new interfaces: `SortedSet` & `LinkedHashSet` implement `SequencedSet`, `List` and `Deque` implement `SequencedCollection`, and `SortedMap` and `LinkedHashMap` implement `SequencedMap`.

The `addFirst` method on `LinkedHashSet` is defined in `SequencedCollection`.

The JDK enhancement proposal does not explain why `LinkedHashSet` didn't have an `addFirst` method before.  But in its [motivation](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431#Motivation) section, it explains why it and the other sequence-related methods were added by the feature.

> Java’s [collections framework](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/doc-files/coll-index.html) lacks a collection type that represents a sequence of elements with a defined encounter order. It also lacks a uniform set of operations that apply across such collections. These gaps have been a repeated source of problems and complaints.
>
> […]
>
> This is an unfortunate state of affairs. The concept of a collection with defined encounter order exists in multiple places in the collections framework, but there is no single type that represents it. As a result, some operations on such collections are inconsistent or missing, and processing elements in reverse order ranges from inconvenient to impossible. We should fill these gaps.